# How do i get Resources and use on code behind in another xaml file (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, styles

How do i get Resources in another xaml file?

I'm in Data.cs file and i want to access Style resource in Example1.xaml file.

```
Style style1 = Application.Current.Resources["LabelTitleStyle"] as Style;
```

Actually i used like this, but it can only for Main xaml file.(App.xaml)
I want to get Resources in another xaml file.

```
Style style8 = Resources["NumberTitleText"] as Style;
```

Then, 'Resources' get Red underline,  because "NumberTitleText" does not exist current context.

How can I get Resources from another xaml file and use on code behind?

Please Help me!! :(

+++++

`ResourceDictionary res = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/.....example.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
Style style8 = res["NumbertitleText"] as Style;`

I tried this, but res is null. Why can't i bring that dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("..\\myResourcesFile.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
if (Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count > 0)
{
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count - 1);
}
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```